# realtion between xml file

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-parsing

If every student should do some homework.

Students do homework with an element is added to the file.

Now how should the file structure?

Whether this structure is appropriate.

```
<students>
   <student>
       <name>
        abc
       </name>
       <Practice>
          <id>
           1
          </id>
       </Practice>
       <Practice>
          <id>
          2
          </id>
       </Practice>
   <student>


   <student>
       <name>
        def
       </name>
       <Practice>
          <id>
           4
          </id>
       </Practice>
   <student>
</students>
```

Or practice and I put in two separate files؟

Comment: be clear what u want to do???

Comment: How should the file structure.if every student do some practice.

Comment: u want validation in xml so that no student will be able to avoid practice ???

Comment: It is possible that a student does not complete the assignment

Answer (score 0):

One file should be fine. Less IO operations, that should work faster then several files.

Btw. you should add an xml header like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Comment: Did you mean the xml header? I added that one.

Comment: Ehm not sure. What do you mean? Should I add an example to read the data? Do you want to see like I would design that xml document? I mean the structure is a kind of personal flavor.